# I found this strange tooth in Galveston, Texas. What does it belong to?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, teeth

[image: tooth] [image: tooth 2]

I found this on May 7, 2017, on Bolivar Peninsula in Galveston, Texas. What's not visible are the treelike rings inside the tooth and what looks like a tiny interior porous center. It looks like it was considerably larger but broken off.

We're all taking bets on what it is! [image][image]

Comment: Hi welcome to Bio.SE! Neat tooth! :). Could you please include an image from the top of the tooth if possible? Thanks!

Comment: Will do! It will just be a little later this afternoon.

Comment: My dentist said it was human's lower right first molar. I think it's starting to look like cow.

Comment: You should probably find a new dentist if they think that came from a human.

Comment: I'd agree that it looks bovine but there is a lot of homology in teeth so I wouldn't be confident in that determination, might at least be a ruminant though. [See here](http://www.nhm.ac.uk/natureplus/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-57789-89719/Cow+lower+molars+occusal+view.jpg) for some bovine molars.

Comment: Sure, wishful thinking, but for its size it could be [densiovan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denisovan#/media/File:Denisova_Molar.jpg) which would be [awesome](https://www.nature.com/news/controversial-study-claims-humans-reached-americas-100-000-years-earlier-than-thought-1.21886) ... :D

Comment: @BryanKrause I agree that your cow tooth link looks very close.

Comment: @Bryan I think it has something to do with Bison. [This link will take you to some fossil forums.](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=isch&q=teeth+structure+of+buffalo&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5r-ay8OXTAhXLMo8KHUJLBaoQhyYIHw&biw=1366&bih=635&dpr=1#tbm=isch&q=cow+tooth+fossil+forum&imgrc=vSYpc6N7RMty5M:)

Comment: @Tytoalba Why do you think it is a fossil rather than a relatively modern tooth?

Comment: I didn't mean it is a fossil, I found these forums discussing about bovine (Bison) teeth, which can shade some light on this specimen. @BryanKrause

Comment: @Tytoalba Got it. I don't see a single tooth on there that is definitively attributed to a bison that looks like this one, though, is there an example I missed? I think it's more likely to be from common domestic cattle. People raise quite a few cattle in Texas, and there aren't very many bison there these days.

Comment: I didn't do a thorough research and I see it lacks the prominent stylid of a Bison. Never mind.

Comment: This discussion might help: http://www.nhm.ac.uk/natureplus/message/57652

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is a cow tooth. Your image matches above image.
https://www.flickr.com/photos/61377404@N08/12300347505

Comment: I agree with this answer. I grew up on a cattle farm and saw these quite often. But it would be important to know if cattle were ever raised on Bolivar Peninsula. It seems quite small.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely a horse tooth. Check out [this image from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_teeth#/media/File:Palatum_horse.JPG).

Comment: It doesn't look anything like any of the teeth in that horse's mouth. Compare to my link for a bovine molar in the link in the comments above.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a **bison tooth** 
Just saying btw if u have any other bones post them in thefossilforum.com(gives little bit of help with fosills and bones)
How i identified it
 just search on tooth of random animal maybe you/ll see the answer somewhere